# What does $\{(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in\mathbb R^3: x_3 \leq x_2 \leq x_1 \}$ look like?

Tags: geometry

What does $\{(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in\mathbb R^3: x_3 \leq x_2 \leq x_1 \}$ look like? 
It seems to be a linear convex cone with vertex at the origin.
I am trying to visualize it but cannot. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x_2\ge x_3$ is a closed halfspace.  $x_1\ge x_2$ is also a closed halfspace.  Your region is the intersection of these two halfspaces.

Comment: If you take two adjacent octants and rotated it, that's the region.  For example $x_1\ge 0, x_2\ge 0$, $x_3$ arbitrary.

Answer (score 7):

`RegionPlot3D[x <= y && y <= z, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]` seems to do the job in Mathematica.[image]

Comment: This picture is deceptive; it suggests that the shape is a three-sided cone.

Comment: yes, i wish i could have gotten in other coordinate systems too.